# Django - sometimes request.POST is mutable, sometimes it isn't

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on some legacy Django code. I have two nearly-identical views:

```
@login_required
def foo(request):
    assert False, "foo mutable=%s" % request.POST._mutable

@login_required
def bar(request):
    assert False, "foo mutable=%s" % request.POST._mutable
```

Strangely `_mutable` is `True`  for one of the handlers and `False` for the other.

There is no custom middleware and the stack traces on the resulting Django debug page are practically the same.

Sure, I can get around the problem by using `request.POST.copy()` or `request.POST._mutable = True` to make the/a `QueryDict` object mutable, but I'd like to know what could be causing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it should always be `False`, the only place in the Django code that sets it to `True` is in the [`MultiPartParser.parse`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/http/multipartparser.py#L122), which only happens if the `CONTENT_TYPE` starts with `multipart`.

From [`_load_post_and_files`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/http/__init__.py#L233) in `HttpRequest`:

```
if self.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').startswith('multipart'):
    self._raw_post_data = ''
    try:
        self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, self)
        ...
```

From [`parse_file_upload`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/http/__init__.py#L200):

```
parser = MultiPartParser(META, post_data, self.upload_handlers, self.encoding)
return parser.parse()
```

And from [`MultiPartParser.parse`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/http/multipartparser.py#L122):

```
self._post = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
...
return self._post, self._files
```

So if one view is getting multipart requests and the other is not, that would explain the difference.